# How do I bind an object that is periodically modified to a treeview in C# WPF using the CommunityToolkit.MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `treeView` defined in XAML as:

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <models:TreeLines x:Key="myLines" x:Name="myLinesData"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView
    x:Name="treeData"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Padding="0,5,0,0"
    Background="#282828"
    BorderThickness="0"
    SelectedValuePath="Uid">
    <TreeViewItem
        x:Name="tLines"
        Uid="tabLines"
        Header="Lines"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myLines}, Path=MyLines}"
        Style="{StaticResource custTVItem}">
        <TreeViewItem.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Lines}" ItemsSource="{Binding lineSet}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding productName}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:LineSets}" ItemsSource="{Binding lineName}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding setName}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:LineNames}" ItemsSource="{Binding dataTypes}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding lineName}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:LineData}" ItemsSource="{Binding dataVals}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding dataType}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem.Resources>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The `UserControl.Resources` is pointing towards a class:

```
public partial class TreeLines : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MainWindow.treeData.ItemsSource))]
    private List<Lines>? myLines;
}
```

The error I get here is:

The target(s) of [NotifyPropertyChangedFor] must be a (different) accessible property

The object `myLines` I'm trying to bind to has the classes behind, as seen in the `TreeView` `HierarchicalDataTemplates:

```cs
public class Lines
{
    public string productName { get; set; }
    public List<LineSets> lineSet { get; set; }
}

public class LineSets
{
    public string setName { get; set; }
    public List<LineNames> lineName { get; set; }
}

public class LineNames
{
    public string lineName { get; set; }
    public List<LineData> dataTypes { get; set; }
}

public class LineData
{
    public string dataType { get; set; }
    public List<double> dataVals { get; set; }
}
```

If I remove all the CommunityToolkit.MVVM aspects and set my variable:
`private List<Lines>? myLines;` manually by changing it to public and assigning data to it on loading, then it populates on load only.

I need to modify `myLines` on the fly within my C# code which in-turn should update the treeView. You can see I'm trying to achieve this automatically with the data binding but something isn't right.

I think the mistakes could possibly be in the line:

`[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MainWindow.treeData.ItemsSource))]`

and/or possibly the `StaticResource` usage in XAML:

```xml
<TreeViewItem
    x:Name="tLines"
    Uid="tabLines"
    Header="Lines"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myLines}, Path=linesCollection}"
    Style="{StaticResource custTVItem}">
```

Please advise if you can help

Comment: "XAML throws an error"? Does the app build and run?

Comment: Yeah the issue was that I was building on X64 - I switched to Any CPU which has resolved that particular issue - have updated the question

Comment: So what's your current issue?

Comment: In a nutshell - how can I bind myLines to my treeView so that when I modify myLines it automatically updates the treeView.
I think it needs the notifyPropertyChangedFor but I I can't get this to work - I'm also unsure how to correctly set the DataContext

Comment: What exactly do you modify? Your sample code doesn't tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `List<T>` properties with `ObservableCollection<T>`. Then the view will be updated whenever you add or remove items from these collections.

For the view to also update when you change a property of an individual item in a collection, the class of the property that you change should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications.

Here is an example of how you should implement the `Lines` class:

```
public class Lines : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string productName { get; set; }

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<LineSets> lineSet { get; set; }
}
```

Bind to the generated *properties* (starting with an uppercase letter):

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:Lines}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding LineSet}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(MainWindow.treeData.ItemsSource))]** does not need to be added.

There is no need to implement additional notifications. Because **[ObservableProperty]** is already implementing the notification function.
[image]
Check out the auto-generated sources.

**[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(parameter)]**'s parameter should be the name of property inside the class.

```
public partial class TreeLines : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private List<Lines>? myLines;

    public string OtherProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string OtherProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, the possible Arguments of **[NotifyPropertyChangedFor]** are only MyLines, OtherProperty1 , and OtherProperty2.

**[NotifyPropertyChangedFor]** is an attribute indicating that other properties connected within the class have changed

Here's an example.

```
public partial class GetSum : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Sum))]
    private int num1;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Sum))]
    private int num2;

    public int Sum { get => num1 + num2; }
}
```

When calling the setter of Num1 Property,
simultaneously update the Num1 value and Sum value bound to the screen.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:GetSum/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Num1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Num2}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sum}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```